# Read Intergers from file into int variables or Vector3

Tags: c#, file-io, input, xna

How do i input integers from a file into a vector3 or a int variable?
This is my code what works for only string

```
using (var enviromentPos = new FileStream("enviromentPos.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
  using(var input = new StreamReader(enviromentPos))
  {
    int line = "";

    while ((line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how can your code only work for `string` the line `int line = "" should not compile..

Answer (score 0):

```
String line="";
List<int> foo = new List<int>()    
while ((line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    int i=0;
    if(int.TryParse(line,out i)) foo.Add(i);
}
```

will read line by line and add all lines which contain something int-parseable to the list as parsed int values

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the code that reads your input:

```
String line = null;
var input = new List<int>();
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    int i = 0;
    if( int.TryParse(line,out i))
    {
       input.Add(i);
    }
}
```

You can either process the list afterwards:

```
var vectors = new List<Vector3>();
for (int index = 0; index < input.Count; index += 3)
{
    vectors.Add(new Vector3(input[index], input[index+1], input[index+2]);
}
```

You would need to make sure that the input was a multiple of three by either truncating it or padding it.

Or you could process the input as you are reading, but then you'd need a counter so that you could execute the `vectors.Add` code every third value read from the file:

```
String line = null;
var input = new List<int>();
int count = 0;
var vectors = new List<Vector3>();
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    int i = 0;
    if( int.TryParse(line,out i))
    {
       input.Add(i);
       count++;
       if (count % 3 == 0)
       {
          vectors.Add(new Vector3(input[count-2], input[count-1], input[count]);
       }
    }
}
```